# connected host has failed to respond, timeout expired

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I try this query in mysql and it works fine but the Query took 103.5772 sec

```
SELECT doctor, 
       SUM(medicine) medicine, 
       sum(radiology) radiology, 
       sum(lab) lab, 
       sum(act) act
FROM ( SELECT max(doctor) doctor, 
  sum( if( pm = 'F', cost, 0.00 ) ) medicine,
  sum( if( pm = 'R', cost, 0.00 ) ) radiology,
  sum( if( pm = 'L', cost, 0.00 ) ) lab,
  sum( if( pm = 'P', cost, 0.00 ) ) act
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY no
  )t
GROUP BY doctor
```

my table has a large amount of data (nearly 2 million data)

when I try in .net, it has an error

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

can I increase the connection timeout?

n.b.
I used this query to connect data

```
conn.ConnectionString = conection.getConnection();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
da.Fill(ds);
return ds;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Connection Timeout, it is timing out on the command due to your data. Adjust the timeout as below;

```
Command.CommandTimeout = 300;
```

For more information : [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I would also suggest you look at your indexes to see if you can optimise the query.

Answer (score -1):

you could user the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property:

`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;`

Comment: This is not a connection timeout.